# "Did" vs "was" sentence example

Tags: sentence-construction, active-vs-passive

Can I use "when did this bridge build" instead of "when this bridge was built" (I think simple past tense is not possible without passive form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use "when did this bridge build" instead of "when this bridge was built"?

No, *"when did this bridge build"* is neither grammatical nor idiomatic. And the other version, *"when this bridge was built"*, is not syntactically correct if it is meant to be a question.

If you are asking someone for the date when something was built, you say something like this:

> When was this bridge built? When did they build this house? When was the Great Wall of China built?

You can use your second version like this:

> It was in 1991 when this bridge was built. When this bridge was built, I was sixteen.

I am not sure what you mean by

> I think simple past tense is not possible without passive form

This is fine: *The Harper government built this bridge in 2008.*

The passive construction would be this: *This bridge was built by the Harper government in 2008.*

Comment: @ManishkumarKumar I don't understand what you are trying to say or ask by your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about past tense, it's whether the verb can be used intransitively.

I'm trying to find a clear rule for when "build" can be intransitive, and I'm not sure I can explain where the cutoff is.

Tension builds, excitement builds, ocean waves build: these are idiomatic to the point of cliché.

Can a pile of rocks build? Wow, that pile is building, it's taller every day. When did it build to that height? I would consider it pedantry to say, "It's not building, someone is building it".

But bridges and buildings don't build; they get built. Why can a pile of rocks build when a building can't? Somehow when a thing takes a complex form, rather than just amassing substance, we don't use "build" intransitively. We need an agent.